# How to run developement server in new angular project?

Tags: angular

I have created a new angular project but i don't known it run.

Please help me.

I have created a new angular project but i don't known it run.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it with using `ng serve`.

Comment: 'ng' is not recognized command.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app using this command. `ng serve`
As per the comment, if you are getting 'ng' is not recognized command', Check whether you have installed angular CLI. `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Use this command to install angular cli. For more refer this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Looks like cli is not installed globally .. !